# Make a cell (but not the first one) always visible on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I had a `UIScrollView` with a `UIImage` above a `UISegmentedControl` above my `UITableView`. I was disabling the scrolling of the `TableView` until the `Image` disappeared so I could finally enable the scrolling but sadly there was a delay on it, meaning I had to remove my finger from the screen in order to refresh the scrolling property, which I didnt like so I started again.

Now I'm getting my `tableView` with his customs cells. The thing is I want the cell with the `segmentedControl` to stay on top of my tableView. To make it easier to understand, if I scroll on cells 10, 11 and 12, I should see: cell 1 (the one with the `segmentedControl`on it) , 10, 11, 12  but if I scroll to the top, I should get cell 0, 1, 2, 3.

I can't seem to find any solution but the Twitter IOS Application does seem to manage it, any solutions for my problem ?

Comment: can you share a screenshot, don't quite get what you're trying to do?

Comment: why don't you use tableHeaderView ??? 
Make the custom View with segmentedControl inside and assign it to tableHeaderView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try splitting your tableView into two sections, where cell 0 is in the first section, cell 1 is the header for the second section, and cells 2...n are in the second section.  This would probably give you the behavior you want ('cell 1' always visible) without having to fight the normal UI behavior.

Comment: This was it, spliting my cells into sections until the selected cell could become a headerView. Thanks for the tip !